# How do I Invoke 3 REST endpoints in parallel?

Tags: java, rest, concurrency

I have to invoke REST endpoints A, B & C in parallel and combine the resulting JSON from each into one JSON. All REST endpoints reside on different servers.

My initial design calls for 3 Callables executed via FutureTasks. I will then do a Future.get(1000ms) on each FutureTask until they return a value. Is this how you would solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I would do it. I really like the [Future interface](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: I'm not really sure what the "That's" is referring to, but great link.

Comment: The original poster's description of his initial design.